# Simple way to check if double value is greater than zero

Tags: java, double, comparator

I have a double variable(**employeeSalary**) and I want to check if this value is greater than(>) zero(**0**). I can think of very naive way to write this code but I am not sure if for **double** data type this is correct way to write.

```
if(employeeSalary > 0){
  // Employee salary is greater than zero.
}else{
  // Employee salary is less than or equal to zero.
}
```

Can anyone please tell me if this approach works?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: certainly it works.

Comment: This should work, but if you really want to go full verbose Java you could use the static method `Double.compare(employeeSalary, 0.0) > 0`, or you know, just use `employeeSalary > 0.0` if you're concerned that `0 != 0.0`

Comment: In the positive case, the meaning of the operator `>` is exactly as expected, `employeeSalary > 0` is `true` when `employeeSalary` is greater than `0`. Of course, the condition is fulfilled when `employeeSalary==0.000000000000000000000000001` and it is not if `employeeSalary` is just `0.000000000000000000000000001` shorter than that. Ask yourself whether that difference really matters and come to the conclusion that you should never use `double` for a salary.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just wanting to compare primitives, you can certainly do something like:

```
if(employeeSalary > 0.0){
  // Employee salary is greater than zero.
}else{
  // Employee salary is less than or equal to zero.
}
```

Note that, if employeeSalary is a double (primitive) then you should really compare this to other double rather than an int.

You could also use a couple Double static methods to do the same

```
// assuming employeeSalary is a double

    if(Double.compare(employeeSalary, Double.valueOf(0.0)) > 0 ){
          // Employee salary is greater than zero.
        }else{
          // Employee salary is less than or equal to zero.
        }
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,%20double)

Comment: Why should `employeeSalary > 0.0` be better than `employeeSalary > 0`? And why do you suggest `Double.compare(employeeSalary, Double.valueOf(0.0)) > 0`?! The method has `Double.compare` has slightly different semantics than `>`, so you should explain them, if you think that’s useful, otherwise, don’t recommend it. And boxing the second argument via `Double.valueOf(0.0)`, just to let it be auto-unboxed right afterwards, makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 3):

There are danger areas when comparing `double` values but using `>` or `<` is not a problem. Your code should work perfectly.

You should, however, be wary of using `==` as there are many edge cases where a number that seems to be `0` is not (e.g. `-0.0`) and a number is effectively zero (e.g. `0.0000...001`) but comparing with `== 0` will fail.